# How to know which popover is being dismissed

Tags: ios

I have a viewcontroller that can show several popovers. Not at the same time. Which would be the best way to know which popover is being dismissed at `popoverControllerDidDismissPopover`?

I have to do different actions regarding the popover that is being dismissed.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work. (This code is not complete - I assume you know basic memory and class management and other stuff so I focus on the actual problem)

In your class keep some ivars to store reference to the popovercontrollers you created

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject <UIPopoverControllerDelegate> {
    UIPopoverController *popover1;
    UIPopoverComtroller *popover2;
}
```

Init your popovercontrollers as usual and save a referance to each of them in popover1 and popover2.

Then in your implementation of the UIPopoverDelegate protocol:

```
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
    if(popoverController == popover1) {
        //popover1 was dismissed
    } else if (popoverController == popover2) {
        //popover2 was dismissed
    }
}
```

EDIT: Looking at your comments, it seems that you mean that you are using only ONE popovercontroller, and replacing it's content view with different UIViewControllers.

If this is the case, I suggest you perform whatever the actions are inside those particular UIViewController in such a way that it affects your application´s state.

Then, once the popover is dismissed, you reload your original view with the new refreshed state.

Or you change it to use two different instances of UIPopoverController instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jake. I would use in the case I have two popovers running at the same time, but it's not the situation. I have only one popover on screen and I need some way to know which one, of the different ones that my viewcontroller has, is on the screen.

Comment: No, they do not need to be running at the same time, this code is for having two popovers that may be shown (one at a time) and determining which one was dismissed by the user, just like you asked for. If this doesn't fit your code, I suggest you post some code so we can see exactly what you´re trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

This is how in Swift as of Xcode 6.3 beta 3, should be *similar* in Objective-C.

1. Your presented view should have a `ViewController` for itself.

   ```
    import UIKit

    class MenuBookmarksViewController: UITableViewController  {
    }
   ```
2. Add an extension to the `UIViewController` class or place **the code (below)** inside the `UIViewController` that will be presenting your popovers:

   ```
   extension UIViewController: UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
     public func popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover(popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) {
          if popoverPresentationController.presentedViewController as? MenuBookmarksViewController != nil {
             ///do your stuff
          }
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You are passed which popover is being dismissed in `popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:`. Use that to determine what you want to do in each case.

You'll probably want to store your `UIPopoverController` instances as ivars of whatever object is presenting them, and then just compare against the value that you're passed in the delegate method.

Comment: Mmmm, I don't see it... I'm not presenting the popovers at the same time. I have a popover to choose a date and another to choose between different values. When I am on popoverControllerDidDismissPopover, how can I know if the popover dismissed was the date or the options one? Now I'm using an NSString instance variable to know which popover is on screen...

Comment: You are passed the popover in `popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:` - that's the only argument to that method. What are you struggling with?

Comment: Maybe my question was not clear. In fact, I need to know which viewcontroller is inside the popover and then, regarding this, do one thing or another on dismissing.

Comment: Then look at the `contentViewController` property of `UIPopoverController` or just do what I said and keep around references to your popover controllers so you can distinguish them.